# Is there a python-equivalent of the unix "file" utility?

Tags: python, unix

I want to have different behavior in a python script, depending on the type of file. I cannot use the filename extension as it may not be present or misleading. I could call the `file` utility and parse the output, but I would rather use a python builtin for portability.

So is there anything in python that uses heuristics to deduce the type of the file from its contents?

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/imghdr.html may be of interest too

Answer (score 18, accepted):

- [python-magic](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/python-magic/)
- [pymagic](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/pymagic/)

Probably others as well. "magic" is the magic keyword to search for. ;-)

Comment: `libmagic` isn't perfect for all files. It looks at the "magic number" in a file header. Text files, such as source code, don't have headers and libmagic has to resort to wild guessing ... it can be very wrong about them.

Comment: Such is the danger of all content-sniffing approaches. Often the number of ‘acceptable’ file types is smaller than the list known by libmagic, in which case ad-hoc app-level sniffing can be a better bet, but for the general case there's not much you can do about it.

Comment: libmagic is what file uses, so it's very, very hard to find a closer match to file.

Comment: just as a note, four years later, pymagic looks like no longer maintained, whereas python-magic is still well alive. Cf [duplicate answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21499463/1290438)

Comment: Update 2014: Both of these are dead.  I think [filemagic](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/filemagic/) is the current library for this functionality.

Comment: Update 2014: My bad.  [python-magic](https://github.com/ahupp/python-magic) is alive and well.