# Python analog for linux "file" command

Tags: python, linux, file

I'm looking for `file` linux command analog made in Python. It should provide information about file type as described in `man file`. Minimal feature set I'm looking for is to determine if file is raw or text (human-readable) one. Wrapper library will be good suggestion.
I know, I can run `file` as subprocess and grab it's output to determine file type. But my program is supposed to parse thousands of files and I'm afraid of very long execution time in this case.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10937350/how-to-check-type-of-files-without-extensions-in-python I thinks it is dup for this one

Answer (score 2):

you need to check the ["magic" byte](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_format#Magic_number) of the file, and I was about to tell you about:

- [python-magic](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/python-magic)

when it occured to me that this question should already have been answered on SO, and [it has](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1974724/is-there-a-python-equivalent-of-the-unix-file-utility).

N.B.: I'm not listing `pymagic` as the other post does, as it did not get any update since `0.1` which looks quite old (even the source website is down).

for OSX:

```
brew install libmagic
pip install python-magic
python
>>> magic.from_file('test.py')
'Python script, ASCII text executable'
```

Comment: it doesn't work on OS X Mavericks :(

Comment: you need to install `libmagic`: `brew install libmagic`

Comment: And it fails on unicode filenames :(